# How to Scrape data from chart on https://bitinfocharts.com

Tags: python, web-scraping, graph, charts

I would like to **scrape** data from a tweet's volume chart on https://bitinfocharts.com into some kind of data file using python or r. I'm very new to python and do not know how to do this. I've looked at other questions in the forum but I was not able to do it

The chart I'm interested in is the following: https://bitinfocharts.com/comparison/decred-tweets.html#1y

I'm looking for a data table with each date and the respective number of tweets for that day as the columns.

I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: Hi alienalex, glad to see you asked your first question! Could you please take a moment to read how to [write a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)? Cheers!

Comment: FYI it's __scrape__ (and __scraping__, __scraped__, __scraper__) not scrap. 'To scrap' means to throw away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible there is more elegant solution, but the data is embedded within the script tags. It's just a matter of pulling that out and parsing it into a table:

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import re


def parse_strlist(sl):
    clean = re.sub("[\[\],\s]","",sl)
    splitted = re.split("[\'\"]",clean)
    values_only = [s for s in splitted if s != '']
    return values_only


url = 'https://bitinfocharts.com/comparison/decred-tweets.html#1y'
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

scripts = soup.find_all('script')
for script in scripts:
    if 'd = new Dygraph(document.getElementById("container")' in script.text:
        StrList = script.text
        StrList = '[[' + StrList.split('[[')[-1]
        StrList = StrList.split(']]')[0] +']]'
        StrList = StrList.replace("new Date(", '').replace(')','')
        dataList = parse_strlist(StrList)

date = []
tweet = []
for each in dataList:
    if (dataList.index(each) % 2) == 0:
        date.append(each)
    else:
        tweet.append(each)

df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(date, tweet)), columns=["Date","Decred - Tweets"])
```

**Output:**

```
print (df)
           Date Decred - Tweets
0    2018/01/08              69
1    2018/01/09             200
2    2018/01/10             163
3    2018/01/11             210
4    2018/01/12             256
5    2018/01/13             185
6    2018/01/14             147
7    2018/01/15             119
8    2018/01/16             169
9    2018/01/17             176
10   2018/01/18             209
11   2018/01/19             179
12   2018/01/20             274
13   2018/01/21             124
14   2018/01/22             185
15   2018/01/23             110
16   2018/01/24             109
17   2018/01/25              86
18   2018/01/26              49
19   2018/01/27            null
20   2018/01/28            null
21   2018/01/29            null
22   2018/01/30            null
23   2018/01/31             194
24   2018/02/01             197
25   2018/02/02             163
26   2018/02/03              73
27   2018/02/04              98
28   2018/02/05             210
29   2018/02/06             215
..          ...             ...
680  2019/11/19              58
681  2019/11/20              67
682  2019/11/21              72
683  2019/11/22              79
684  2019/11/23              46
685  2019/11/24              38
686  2019/11/25              81
687  2019/11/26              57
688  2019/11/27              54
689  2019/11/28              60
690  2019/11/29              55
691  2019/11/30              40
692  2019/12/01              39
693  2019/12/02              71
694  2019/12/03              93
695  2019/12/04              44
696  2019/12/05              41
697  2019/12/06              34
698  2019/12/07              40
699  2019/12/08              44
700  2019/12/09              47
701  2019/12/10              47
702  2019/12/11              64
703  2019/12/12              61
704  2019/12/13              67
705  2019/12/14              93
706  2019/12/15              59
707  2019/12/16              86
708  2019/12/17              82
709  2019/12/18              51

[710 rows x 2 columns]
```

Comment: thank you so much, it works perfectly. I really appreciate it. Thank you so much!

Comment: @alienalex in that case you probably should accept and/or upvote the answer. That's how one shows appreciation on SO.